# How to get the chart info from selected chart in active spreadsheet? (google apps script)

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to get specific chart which I selected on active sheet. 
I want to build tool to confirm selected chart size(Width,Height) and show the values on the console log.
I try to use getSelect() and getSelection method, but it didn't work.
if you have the solution, please tell me the method..

```html
function getchartsize(){
 
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
const chart = sheet.getSelection().getCharts();//I'd like to know how to get selected chart info.
const width = chart.getWidth();
const height = chart.getHeight();
console.log(`Width: ${width}/n Height: ${Height}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

You have to get charts directly from the sheet, not from the selection:

```
const chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
```

Then to get height and width, you can get its options first, then get the specific option:

```
const width = chart.getOptions().get('width');
const height = chart.getOptions().get('height');
```

**Sample Output:**

[image]

**References:**

[Class Sheet | getCharts()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getCharts())

[Class Embedded Chart | getOptions()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart#getoptions)

[Class Chart Options | get(option)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/chart-options.html)

Comment: Hello, Carlos. Thanks for your advice.
I have another question.
Your proposal seems this method is for the case only one chart  is on active sheet.
I'd like to know how to detect specific chart when some charts are on the active sheet.
In that case, are there no way  to detect specific chart?

Comment: You would have to go through the chart array and check for a specific attribute, like the anchor position. In that case, you could use ````sheets.getCharts[i].getContainerInfo().getAnchorColumn()```` or ````getAnchorRow()```` and check one by one.

Comment: `sheet.getCharts()` get all the charts in the sheet, but is there a way to get the `selected` chart ?