# How to get the selected chart in a Google spreadsheet with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to change the color of charts in Google spreadsheet. This is working for all charts in one sheet.

```
function colorChart() {
  let $Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let $Charts = $Sheet.getCharts();
  let $Colors = {
    'One': '#6E6E6E',
    'Two': '#FFED00',
    'Three': '#238C96',
  };

  for (let $i in $Charts) {
    let $Chart = $Charts[$i].modify()
      .setOption('series.0.color', $Farben['One'])
      .setOption('series.1.color', $Farben['Two'])
      .setOption('series.2.color', $Farben['Three'])
      .build();
    $Sheet.updateChart($Chart);
  }
}
```

In the documentation I can only find `getCharts()` which returns an array of all charts in the active sheet.

Is it possible to get the selected chart only?

Unfortunately the question was not answered here: [How to get the chart info from selected chart in active spreadsheet? (google apps script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67708027/how-to-get-the-chart-info-from-selected-chart-in-active-spreadsheet-google-app)

Using `$Sheet.getCharts()[0]` as mentioned in the post was not working since only the first chart of the sheet was returned.

Comment: It seems it is not possible. Would you like to check a possible workaround instead?

Comment: For sure. 
What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *SUGGESTION/WORKAROUND*

The challenge here is that [`SpreadsheetApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) class in Apps Script doesn't seem to have a dedicated method to get the selection of a `chart` or any movable/re-sizeable elements on a sheet but only for selected cells/rows.

As a workaround, perhaps you can try an implementation using a custom **HTML** page that will give you an option to view currently created charts from the sheet *(via **custom menu** & **custom sidebar**)* and from there, you will be able to have an option to select a chart from that **HTML** interface & apply the changes.

## Demo

- ***Sample***: Edit the Pie Chart

[image]

- Sample drop-down menu on the HTML page *(due to limitations of drop-down on screen capture)*

[image]

## Sample apps script file & HMTL file:

> ***NOTE:*** Community members don't code for you **but** you can use these sample codes ***(derived from several sample codes scoured over the internet)*** below to get you started.

`Code.gs`

```
/**Creates a custom menu to load an edit chart sidebar.*/
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
    .createMenu('Edit Chart')
    .addItem('Start', 'showSidebar')
    .addToUi();
}

/**Shows the custom html sidebar.*/
function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
    .setTitle('Edit Charts');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showSidebar(html);
}

/**Function to return the current charts on a sheet.*/
function getCurrentChartsOnSheet() {
  var charts = buildMenu();
  return charts;
}

/**Function to get the current charts on a sheet.*/
function buildMenu() {
  var getChartsMenu = [];
  let $Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let $Charts = $Sheet.getCharts();

  for (let $i in $Charts) {
    var currentChart = $Charts[$i].getOptions().get('title');
    getChartsMenu.push([$i + ' - ' + (currentChart.length < 1 ?
      $Charts[$i].modify().getChartType().toString() : currentChart)])
  }

  return getChartsMenu; //Structure of the array will be: [chart index #] - [Chart type]
}

/**Function to edit the selected chart.*/
function editSelectedChart(selection) {
  let $Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let $Charts = $Sheet.getCharts();
  let $Colors = {
    'One': '#6E6E6E',
    'Two': '#FFED00',
    'Three': '#238C96',
  };

  let $Chart = $Charts[selection.match(/\d+/g)].modify()
    .setOption('series.0.color', $Colors['One'])
    .setOption('series.1.color', $Colors['Two'])
    .setOption('series.2.color', $Colors['Three'])
    .build();
  $Sheet.updateChart($Chart);
}
```

`Page.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Edit Charts</title>

<head>
  <style>
    .space {
      width: 4px;
      height: auto;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getCurrentChartsOnSheet();

    function onSuccess(data) {
      var select = document.getElementById("selectChart");
      var options = data;
      for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
          var opt = options[i];
          var el = document.createElement("option");
          el.textContent = opt;
          el.value = opt;
          select.appendChild(el);
      }
    }

    function passSelectedChart(){
      var e = document.getElementById("selectChart");
      google.script.run.editSelectedChart(e.value); //<-- PASS the selected drop-down data to GOOGLE SCRIPT function named editSelectedChart()
    }
          
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <h3>Choose a chart to edit:</h3>
  <select id="selectChart">
    <option>No Selection</option>
  </select>

  <div>
    <p><input type="button" value="Apply" onclick="passSelectedChart()"></p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p><input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()"></p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

## References

- [Apps Script Custom sidebars](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars)
- [Apps Script Custom Menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus)
- [Class HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service)
- [HTML DOM Element appendChild()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)
- [google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: @Alex Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thank you @SputnikDrunk2 this kind of works.

Comment: I wonder why you use function `getCurrentChartsOnSheet()` instead of calling `buildMenu()` directly. What is the advantage of doing it this way?

Comment: It is not very convenient to use the chart types as description. I would suggest to use `$Charts[$i].getOptions().get('title')`  instead. Which works as long as there is a title and takes me back to the originally question.

Comment: @Alex apologies for the confusion, I have only separated the `getCurrentChartsOnSheet()` from calling `buildMenu()` for readability when I was testing it. I know it is kind of redundant, so you could call the `buildMenu()` in your actual code instead. Regarding the names of charts, I got your point with the **titles** instead of using **chart types** as it makes more sense. I made a little change on the line for pushing the chart names. It will use the **chart title** (if available) otherwise, the **chart type** will be used.